# How to convert array to array of array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to convert single array to array of array?

This is below present code, which is not working

```
array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
array2 = [];

onClick() {
 this.array2 = this.array2.push(this.array1);
 console.log(this.array2);
}
```

Desired output is

```
array2  = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']];
```

Comment: You do not need to assign the result of `this.array2.push(this.array1);` back to this.array2

Comment: `Array.prototype.push()`: _"The push() method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and **returns the new length of the array**."_

Comment: do you want to push always the array to an array? or just a single time? maybe a purpose would help to get you an answer with a better code for the future. btw, why are you using `this`?

Comment: Cannot use this for declaration as this is Angular code.

Comment: @R.H, share more your codes including the object/class with the method `onClick`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to remove variable from pushing statement. like

```
 array2.push(array1);
 console.log(array2);
```

```js
const array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
const arr2 = [];
arr2.push(array1);
console.log(arr2);
```

Comment: he don't need to assign push statement to variable.

array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
array2 = [];

// this.array2 = this.array2.push(this.array1);
// it should be like this
 array2.push(array1);
 console.log(array2);

Answer (score 1):

You can do that simply with `const array2 = [array1];`

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
this.array1 = ['a','b','c','d','e']
this.array2 = []
onClick() {
    this.array2.push(this.array1);
}
```

Explanation:
Not using 'this' will make you a global variable, where the object's (this) array1 and array2 will remain a undefined. So you need to declare array1 and array2 in the object by using 'this' before the two declarations.

Comment: Why should OP do this? What's the problem? How did you fix it?

Comment: It would help to add some explanation for OP to understand his issue.

Comment: This solution is throwing error as "Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'."

Comment: This is Angular code, it will throw error if we use this for declaration

Comment: Please specify Angular next time, thx!